# How to get the ray equation of a 2d point in world space

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, computer-vision

I'm looking to get the world space ray equation of an `(x, y)` point in 2D space. So given `(x, y)`, id like to get something like:

```
(x, y, z) = (x0, y0, z0) + t*(a, b, c)
```

where `(x0, y0, z0)` and `(a, b, c)` are vectors which I know.

I'm using the solvePnP function in OpenCV to turn a 3D model into 2D coordinates, so I have the rotation vector, transition vector, camera matrix and distortion coefficients. Can someone please explain the math necessary to get this ray equation in world space?

Comment: Please clarify the problem.  What is the reference system for this 2-D point, and how does that related to the 3-D world space?  Explaining the paradigm will get you more help from mathematicians.

Comment: The 2-D point is basically the (x, y) coordinates of a point detected from the camera. I want to project this point onto a cylinder-like shape in 3-D world.

Comment: So in order to do that, I want to get the ray equation of the point, and do the math for the intersection. Does that make sense? Sorry, I'm a little new to this so let me know if I'm missing something out

Comment: Getting much closer; thanks.  I take it that (x0, y0, z0) is the camera position, and (a, b, c) is a vector derived from the 2-D point.  How does the the camera's 2-D system align with the World Space?  I envision that the camera interprets its view as if it were centered in a cylinder of unit radius, which is "unzipped" at some invisible point to the rear and flattened to extract pseudo-Catrtesian coordinates.

Comment: For instance, something 10 degrees to the left of center and 15 degrees above the virtual horizon might be regarded as point (-10, +15) in 2-D space.  You want to translate that to (x0, y0, z0) + t*(a, b, c) ... where a, b, c are trig functions of -10 and 15 (and combinations thereof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here what I would do.

For a 2D image point in `[u, v]` coordinate, undistort the 2D coordinate and apply the reverse perspective transformation. OpenCV has already a function [`undistortPoints()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga55c716492470bfe86b0ee9bf3a1f0f7e) that do that.

You will obtain a 3D coordinate in the normalized camera frame, that means at `z=1`.

For the line / ray [equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfLines.aspx), you have a starting point at `(x0=0, y0=0, z0=0)` and another point at `(x, y, z=1)`.

---

Note about the reverse perspective transformation.

For a given camera matrix:
[image: camera matrix]

The reverse perspective transformation is just:
[image: reverse perspective transformation]

---

Note about frame coordinate transformation:

For a given world (or object) 3D point:
[image: world 3D coordinate]

If you know the camera pose (using for example `solvePnP()`), you have the transformation matrix [image: cTw]:

[image: cTw 2]

To compute the 3D coordinate in the camera frame:

[image: transformation]